# Returning search results inside of a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, search

We followed Ryan Bates' Railscast #37, and the search form appears without error on our app, but is not functional. It doesnt return any search results.

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
  @title = "All users"

  @users = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

The search function is defined in our user.rb file

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
  where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
  all
 end
end
```

and finally our index.html.erb file where that search box is displayed

```
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your index.html.erb doesn't seem to contain any code to actually display the selected @users?

Comment: we think thats the issue. how would we go about displaying the `@users`  based upon search keys typed into the text field?

Comment: With your current code, @users will be filtered based upon the query submitted by the search form.  For displaying results in index.html.erb, see the code I previously posted in my answer below.

Comment: Have you written unit tests for your search and verified that it is working the way you think it is?

Comment: @onemanarmy the search form is now fully functional with a few tweaks, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @MarcTalbot we are so new to rails we dont have much knowledge of approaching custom written tests.

Comment: I'd suggest learning testing strategies before going much further in rails.  There are some fantastic test frameworks for both ruby and Rails, and you'd be insane not to use them.  The ruby community has probably embraced Test Driven Development far more than any other software community as a whole.

Comment: what TDD frameworks do you recommend using

Answer (score 2):

Are you looping though somewhere to display the results?  You do have matching records in the database, right?

```
# create some users in the console
User.create([{:name => "Bo Jangles"}, {:name => "Some dude"}])

# somewhere in index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p><%= user.name %></p>
<% end %>
```